# Play Mailer Plugin For Play Framework 2.4 Does Not Work With Outlook Office 365

Tags: playframework, smtp, imap, office365, mailer

I am trying to get the Play Mailer plugin to work with an office 365 email account but receive the following error:

> Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.office365.com:995]

Using MS recommended settings we have tried:

**SMTP**

```
play.mailer {
    host="smtp.office365.com"
    port=995
    ssl=yes
    tls=no
    user="XXXX@XXXX.com"
    password=“XXXXX
}

play.mailer {
    host="smtp.office365.com"
    port=587
    ssl=no
    tls=yes
    user="XXXX@XXXX.com"
    password="XXXXX"
}
```

**IMAP**:

We also attempted to use IMAP settings

```
play.mailer {
    host="outlook.office365.com"
    port=993
    ssl=yes
    tls=no
    user="XXXX@XXXX.com"
    password="XXXXX"
}
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just don't think that play mailer works. There doesn't seem to be any working examples of this anywhere and as it's 2017 - it's probably been deprecated now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re connecting to your Office 365 email using SMTP:

Your email program may automatically try to use server port 25 for SMTP. If your email program shows port 25 for SMTP, be sure to select TLS encryption. Then, enter 587 to replace the default port number (25):
server name: smtp.office365.com , Port: 587, Encryption method: Transport Layer Security (TLS) .

If you’re connecting to your Office 365 email using IMAP:

Your email program may automatically try to use port 110 if you're using POP or port 143 if you're using IMAP. If your email program shows port 110 or 143, be sure to select SSL encryption. Then, enter a port number of 995 to replace the default port number (110) if you're using POP or a port number of 993 to replace the default port number (143) if you're using IMAP:
server name: outlook.office365.com, Port: 993, Encryption method: SSL .

Comment: Thanks for the response Nan Yu. I think the tried configurations in my OP match your answer (IMAP on 993/SSL and SMTP on 587/TLS) but these settings still produce the **server failed error**. 

Any further ideas would be much appreciated.